# Android Workmanager and Admob conflict

Tags: android, gradle, dependencies, admob, android-workmanager

I have an android kotlin app that is using WorkManager to schedule and do some tasks. When i added the Admob dependency the scheduling in WorkManager became broken and does not do tasks in the background unless the app is running. These are the dependencies:

```
dependincies {
    // WorkManager
    implementation "androidx.work:work-runtime-ktx:2.8.1"
    implementation "androidx.work:work-multiprocess:2.8.1"
    // Google Ads
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:21.5.0'
}
```

I tried using different versions of admob. Using Admob 22.4.0 resulted in a compile error when using `setForegroundAsync()` function that states there is a conflict or missing dependencies. Using Admob 21.5.0 works fine but breaks scheduling of workers regardless of being periodic or onetime. I have tried it in a physical device (Xiaomi) and have all background restrictions disabled.

Comment: I tried downgrading WorkManager to 2.7.0 and now scheduling works fine in the background. I still don't know exactly what is the cause of this and correct solution for it.